# Integro-Differential Equation Techniques with Definite Integrals

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Suppose $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(x,P(x),P'(x))dx=0$ I have read several sources which state to use Laplace transformations. However, I am struggling to see how to use Laplace transforms as the resultant LHS function is a constant.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @J126 I am not trying to prove anything rather figure out what $P(x)$ is or a solution set of it.

Comment: What is the resultant LHS when you use Laplace transforms?

Comment: @J126 Im not sure how to take it since the LHS is constant.